# Joint Probability Distribution Function Questions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have a joint distribution probability function $g(x,y)$ of two correlated random variables X and Y, does the following equality hold?

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{b} g(x,y) dx dy=\int_{-\infty}^{b} g(x) dx,$ where $g(x)$ is a distribution probability function of X.

If it does, how can we prove it?

Regards
Ray

Comment: do you mean probability **density** function? As for a proof, start with the definition of a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tonelli's Theorem since $g$ is non-negative and measurable (wrt the random variables).
$$\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{-\infty}^b g(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y = \int_{-\infty}^b\bbox[cornsilk,1pt]{{\int_{\Bbb R}g(x,y)\operatorname dy}}\operatorname d x$$